# Does the gavel have a legal significance, or is it purely ceremonial?

Tags: united-states, rules-of-court, judge

Judges in US courtrooms famously use a gavel at appropriately dramatic points in a trial.  If a judge fails to use a gavel, or uses it at the wrong moment, is this legally significant?  Or is the gavel purely ceremonial?

Answer (score 12):

It is purely ceremonial. The tendency in modern jurisprudence is towards the practical and away from legalisms and technicalities. Even if a judge used a gavel in some way inappropriately, it would be unlikely to have any legal significance for anyone but the judge.

An argument based on gavel misuse would fall into the "fringe-on-the-flag" category of legal arguments (yes, there are people who think that the court's powers are determined entirely by the fringe on the courhouse flag). The gavel is a traditional trapping of a common law courtroom, but has no legal significance.

Comment: Can you bolster this answer with some references that would back up your claims in your answer?

Comment: @Chad: That falls into the realm of "proving a negative."

Comment: I really do not think so *The tendency in modern jurisprudence is towards the practical* & *"fringe-on-the-flag"* & *there are people who think that the court's powers are determined entirely by the fringe on the courhouse flag*  are all things that should be relatively easy to reference assuming what you say is true.  And if it is purely ceremonial then I would think that would be referable too.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gavel

Comment: Do gavels share a common ancestor with ceremonial maces?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceremonial_mace

Comment: @Chad: I'll try to dig some references up (I've seen this before, in sovereign citizen "arguments". In particular, I recall the "fringe on the flag" argument being that the fringe belongs on/denotes an admiralty court, which would not be authorized to hear the case in question. I believe these "sovereign citizen" arguments are what chapka was referring to.

Comment: FWIW I've never seen any statute or court rule referring to a gavel in either state or federal court. It is just a tradition, much like wearing robes. A judge can issue a valid legal ruling in a suit, or pajamas at home, or even in shorts on a golf course, and in search warrant cases not infrequently does.

Comment: The gavel is not ‘a traditional trapping of a common law courtroom’ – it is an American idiosyncrasy. [It is not, and never was, used in English courts.](https://www.theguardian.com/uk/2009/nov/23/writ-large-courtroom-drama-bbc)

Comment: If some “sovereign citizen” claimed a judgement wasn’t legal because the gavel was not used, would a judge repeat the judgement, this time using the gavel?